# Sublime Text selection issue

Tags: sublimetext3

In my Sublime Text (v3), there seems to be some issue suddenly with selection. So assume I have the following code;

```
const testvar = '123';
```

1. Earlier, if I double clicked on either const Or testvar, it just selected that. However for some reason, it is now selecting both const & testvar
2. Earlier, if I had my cursor at the start of line and did Ctrl + Right arrow, it would take me to start of next word i.e. testvar. But now, it seems to be hoppinh over 2 words and cursor goes to =

Not sure if some setting got changed unintentionally.

Comment: Does this happen in any other contexts? For example, if you put the cursor in front of `testvar` and hit Ctrl-Right, does it select `testvar =`?

Comment: Nope...strangely, it seems to be an issue when selecting from the start of line...So if I put the cursor in front of testvar and hit Ctrl-Right, it does select testvar (does not select the = which I think seems fine)